# javascript for position fixed on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this div which is just a title.

```
<div class="container-fluid DFOCpadding">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class=" text-center ">
        <span class="toptext">DANCE FOR OVARIAN CANCER</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and a nav bar under it which I'd like to position as fixed

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Dance Dance</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="http://danceforovariancancer.com.au">HOME</a></li>             
            <li><a class="scroll" href="#register"><span class="register">REGISTER</span></a></li>
            <li><a class="scroll" href="#faq">FAQ's</a></li>    
            <li><a class="scroll" href="#acts">ACTS</a></li>    
            <li><a class="scroll" href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>  
            <li><a class="scroll" href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>      
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

and I need the page to just catch the navbar when you scroll past it like on this site: https://ovariancancer.net.au/

I have seen answers for this but they are very restricted to the OP's use case and so I can't get it to work for my page.

cheers

Comment: whts the css for DFOCpadding?

Comment: Hi, just a  new class "navbar-fixed" in bootstrap, then your work is done

Comment: @LuckyChingi just padding 20px top and bottom for the title :)

Comment: @MarmikBhatt but this will send it to the top and cover the header div, cheers

Comment: @lopu have a look at my answer below and adjust the if statement to match the padding

Comment: you can modify this by adding your custom class and add padding or margin so that it will change it's position, but make it fixed

Comment: @LuckyChingi thank-you worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Her's the code similar to 'https://ovariancancer.net.au/'

hope this helps

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $(".navbar").css({
      'position': 'fixed',
      'top': '0px',
      'width': '100%',
      'background': '#cfcfcf',
      'z-index': '99'
    });
  } else {
    $(".navbar").css({
      'position': 'relative',
      'background': '#FFFFFF',
      'width': '100%'
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid DFOCpadding">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class=" text-center ">
        <span class="toptext">DANCE FOR OVARIAN CANCER</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Dance Dance</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="http://danceforovariancancer.com.au">HOME</a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="scroll" href="#register"><span class="register">REGISTER</span></a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="scroll" href="#faq">FAQ's</a>
          </li>

          <li><a class="scroll" href="#acts">ACTS</a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="scroll" href="#about">ABOUT</a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="scroll" href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>      <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>      <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>      <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>      <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>      <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>      <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>      <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>      <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>      <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>      <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
  <P>&nbsp;</p>
```

Comment: what does $(window).scroll(function() do?

Comment: Check if window is scrolled and returns a value

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
.navbarfixed {
    position: fixed;
 }



$(function() {
var nav = $(".navbar");
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 500) {
        nav.addClass("navbarfixed");
    } else {
        nav.removeClass("navbarfixed");
    }
});
});
```

Comment: but it should fixed on scroll not before

Comment: try it now @Shubham Patel

Comment: can you except the answer?

Comment: I can't because who asked the question only he/she except

Comment: I don't think I can use this because removing the whole navbar class would stuff up the styling, unless I make the navbarfixed include all the same styling with just the position: fixed and relative changing?

Comment: no it does not remove the class it adds a class then when you are back at the top it removes the added class so it is no longer fixed @lopu